# Realm write transaction failing, despite being in transaction

Tags: swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I have this code, which should append `messages` with a new `message`:

```
func addMessage(_ message: Message) {
    do {
        try Realm().write {
            self.messages.append(message)
        }
    } catch let error {
        print("could not add message due to error:\n\(error)")
    }
}
```

However, I get an exception `Cannot modify managed RLMArray outside of a write transaction` It doesn't make any sense to me, because I'm already in a write transaction...

Comment: You might have some getter/setter of your current object which are being used by Realm. Providing more code could be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble was I was using a plain `Realm` object with no special configuration. Since I am using Realm Mobile Platform, I needed to create a `Realm` object with the same config each time I want to write to that DB:

```
let configuration = Realm.Configuration(
                syncConfiguration: SyncConfiguration(user: user, realmURL: URL(string: "realm://127.0.0.1:9080/~/speciail")!)
            )
self.realm = try! Realm(configuration: configuration)

//now do the write transaction!
```

It took a bit of refactoring, but I have it now. My thanks to those of you who took the time to help me.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a `Realm` object before applying the `write` module.

According to the [GitHub documentation](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxRealm), you can try code like this:

```
func addMessage(_ message: Message) {
    do {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        try! realm.write {
            self.messages.append(message)
        }
    } catch let error {
        print("Could not add message due to error:\n\(error)")
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I'm afraid to say it does not have an effect.

Comment: Shoot! I guess can we see some of your other code? In particular I think it might be useful to see where you declare `self.messages.append`! Sorry the code didn't work!

Comment: Thanks again for your time. I never declared `messages.append`. It comes with Realm's `List`: `let messages = List<Message>()`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `let realm = try! Realm()` with a custom default configuration by setting a default configuration see [here](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#realm-configuration):

```
  var config = Realm.Configuration()

  // Set this as the configuration used for the default Realm
  Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
```

Comment: Yes this is the best way of it. The error message was throwing me off, but essentially, I just needed to use the same configuration everywhere. Thanks!